# Replication across AZ

Tags: ignite, apacheignite

We have a 6-node cluster setup in which 3 server nodes are spread across 3 availability zones and each zone also has a client node. All is set up in a Kubernetes-based service.
Important configurations,

1. storeKeepBinary = true
2. cacheMode = Partitioned (some cache's about
   5-8, out of 25 have this as TRANSACTIONAL)
3. AtomicityMode = Atomic
4. backups = 1 readFromBackups = false
5. no persistence for these tests

When we run it locally on physical boxes, we get a decent throughput. However when we deploy this in the cloud in an AZ-based setup in k8s. We see a steep drop. We can only get a performance comparable to on-prem cluster tests when we keep only a single cache node without any backups (backups=0).

I get that a different hardware and n/w latency in cloud come into play. And while i investigate all that wrt to the differences in cloud, i want to understand if there are some obvious behavioral issues under the cover wrt to ignite that i trying to understand a few things outline below,

1. Why should cache get calls be slower? It's a partitioned data, so lookup should be by key and since we have turned off 'readFrombackup', it should always go the primary partition. So adding number of cache servers should not change any of the get call latencies.
2. Similar for 'inserts/puts', other than the caches where the atomicity is 'Transactional', everything else should be the same when we go from one cache to 3 caches.
3. Any other areas anyone can suggest which i can take a look from configuration/etc.

TIA

Comment: How stretched the cluster is? Where your AZs are located? Are they inside the same data region? What cloud is it?

Comment: AWS, AZ's across different regions. I get there could be some n/w latency. But does that matter given the above configuration for 'get' & 'put'. Maybe only if 'get'/'put' is going to the furthest node? Is there a way to make sure they always go to the nearest node?

Comment: There is no nearest node concept for a partitioned cache. Ignite will always use primary partition owner for a key lookup. If your client is in AZ1 and primary partition is in AZ3, a request will be made to AZ3 regardless of whether it's a put or get operation.

Comment: I suppose that could be implemented for replicated caches with some modification. But in general, your guess is correct; I'd definitely expect performance degradation for different regions because of the latency.

Comment: May I ask you why there is a need to have 3 different regions? What was the idea behind it? Fault tolerance? Latency reduction?

Comment: FT is the primary rationale behind this deployment model. Is there a way we can pin data coming from one client to always go to one server?

Comment: I suppose you did configure the affinity backup filter correctly for FT?

Comment: What you are suggesting - sticking to a concrete node could be implemented, for example using an affinity key. But the general approach seems to be not quite correct. It's not recommended to have such a stretched cluster because of the network.

Comment: Have you considered the following: having 3 different clusters, but having a data replication between them with some delay. I.e. not all data would be available right away, but after some synchronization window?

Comment: Yes, we are using AZ affinity backup filter. Usually these cloud providers provide a guarantee on n/w latency, the last i checked it was 0.7ms within region across AZ's. Replication across clusters would i suppose need a more involved custom implementation or then a paid Ignite version, OSS version does not do this, please confirm.

Comment: Looking at cross-cluster replication, i suppose a Kafka Connect like approach could be used i.e. streaming cache ops to Kafka and then onto another Ignite cluster? Or is there something better as well?

Comment: Yes, I think Kafka is a recommended way of Ignite replication. For GridGain there is a separate big feature available https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/administrators-guide/data-center-replication